# Improving Generic List Comparator

Tags: c#, list, generics, comparator

I need a generic class to compare two list instances. I have the code below, but it is quite messy and inefficient. How can I make it better and definitely faster?

CallByName is an extension that uses reflection to get the property.

```
public class ListObjectComparator
{ 
    #region PROPRIETES

    public List<object> NewList {get; private set;}
    public List<object> RemovedList { get; private set; }
    public List<object> CommunList { get; private set; }

    #endregion


    #region METHODES PUBLICS

    public bool Run<T>(string iCommunTextPropertyName, List<T> iOriginalList, List<T> iNewList)
    {
        return Run(iCommunTextPropertyName, iOriginalList, iCommunTextPropertyName, iNewList);
    }

    public bool Run<T>(string iOriginalPropertyName, List<T> iOriginalList,string iNewPropertyName, List<T> iNewList)
    {
        if (iOriginalPropertyName.IsNotNull() &&
            iNewPropertyName.IsNotNull() &&
            iOriginalList != null &&
            iNewList != null)
        {
            NewList = new List<object>();
            RemovedList = new List<object>();
            CommunList = new List<object>();

            foreach (object originalItem in iOriginalList)
            {
                object research = iNewList.Where(a => a.CallByName(iNewPropertyName).ToString() == originalItem.CallByName(iOriginalPropertyName).ToString()).FirstOrDefault();
                if (research == null)
                {
                    RemovedList.Add(originalItem);
                }
                else
                {
                    CommunList.Add(research);
                }
            }

            foreach (object newItem in iNewList)
            {
                object research = iOriginalList.Where(a => a.CallByName(iOriginalPropertyName).ToString() == newItem.CallByName(iNewPropertyName).ToString()).FirstOrDefault();
                if (research == null) { NewList.Add(newItem); };

            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer:

```
public class ListComparator<TOriginal,TNew>
{

    public ListComparator(IEnumerable<TOriginal> iOriginalList, Func<TOriginal, IComparable> iOriginalProperty, IEnumerable<TNew> iNewList, Func<TNew, IComparable> iNewProperty)
    {
        if (iOriginalProperty == null ||
            iNewProperty == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException(); };

            if (iOriginalList.IsNullOrEmpty() )
            {
                NewList = (iNewList != null) ? iNewList.ToList() : null;
                return;
            }

            if (iNewList.IsNullOrEmpty())
            {
                RemovedList = (iOriginalList != null) ? iOriginalList.ToList() : null;
                return;
            }


            NewList = (from tnew in iNewList.ToList()
                       join toriginal in iOriginalList.ToList()
                       on iNewProperty(tnew)
                       equals iOriginalProperty(toriginal) into gj
                       from item in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
                       where item == null
                       select tnew).ToList();

            CommunList = (from tnew in iNewList.ToList()
                          join toriginal in iOriginalList.ToList()
                          on iNewProperty(tnew)
                          equals iOriginalProperty(toriginal) into gj
                          from item in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
                          where item != null
                          select tnew).ToList();

            CommunPairList = (from tnew in iNewList.ToList()
                              join toriginal in iOriginalList.ToList()
                              on iNewProperty(tnew)
                              equals iOriginalProperty(toriginal) into gj
                              from item in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
                              where item != null
                              select new KeyValuePair<TOriginal, TNew>(item, tnew)).ToList();

            RemovedList = (from toriginal in iOriginalList.ToList()
                           join tnew in iNewList.ToList()
                           on iOriginalProperty(toriginal)
                           equals iNewProperty(tnew) into gj
                           from item in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
                           where item == null
                           select toriginal).ToList();
            return;

    }

    #region PROPRIETES

    public List<TNew> NewList { get; private set; }
    public List<TOriginal> RemovedList { get; private set; }
    public List<TNew> CommunList { get; private set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Obtient la liste de pair avec l'original en key et le nouveau en value
    /// </summary>
    public List<KeyValuePair<TOriginal,TNew>> CommunPairList { get; private set; }

    #endregion

}
```

use:

```
List<Tuple<string, string>> list1 = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();
        List<Tuple<string, string>> list2 = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();

        list1.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("AA", "zefzef"));
        list1.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("A1", "iulyu"));

        list2.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("Abb", "szefez"));
        list2.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("A1", "zevzez"));

        ListComparator<Tuple<string, string>, Tuple<string, string>> comp = new ListComparator<Tuple<string, string>, Tuple<string, string>>(list1, x => x.Item1, list2, a => a.Item1);
```

OUTPUT :

1 commun, 1 removed, 1 new

thanks

Comment: So what is your main problem, that it's slow or that it's not readable/maintainable? Does it work at all? What are you trying to compare and how? Why do you have `List<object>` instead of `List<T>`?

Comment: This seems like more of a code review question. Might be better suited to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I think this belongs on [codereview.se].

Comment: [My implementation of what are you trying to do](https://bitbucket.org/sapiensworks/caveman-tools/src/ce2c7ef851000fb8033bda0fe853100841cad5c2/src/CavemanTools/Extensions/ListUtils.cs?at=default)

Comment: It's hard to tell whet you're trying to do, but it looks like you're comparing two lists of objects by comparing a property by name?  If that's the case it could be done in 1 linq query.

Comment: Maybe you can describe in words what your code is supposed to do.

Comment: Well in words ;) I try to compare two list of differents object comparing one properties with different name. Jim Mischel is close of what I'm looking for but don't know how to build the comparer on two differents properties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the list of items that the two lists share in common, look at [Enumerable.Intersect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb460136%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). That is:

```
var same = OriginalList.Intersect(NewList, comparer);
```

If you want to know which items in `NewList` aren't in `OriginalList` (i.e. the list of added items), you'd use [Enumerable.Except](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb336390%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
var added = NewList.Except(OriginalList, comparer);
```

If you want to know which items were deleted, you use `Except` again, but switch the order:

```
var deleted = OriginalList.Except(NewList, comparer);
```

If you're comparing different properties, then probably your best bet is to create intermediate lists that contain the properties and references to the objects. For example: (There might be typos in the code, but this shows the general idea.)

```
class TempObj: IEquatable<TempObj>
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public object Item { get; set; }
    public bool Equals(TempObj other)
    {
        return Key.Equals(other.Key);
    }
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Key.GetHashCode();
    }
}

var listOrig = OriginalList.Select(x => new TempObj(
    x..CallByName(iOriginalPropertyName).ToString());
var listNew = NewList.Select(x => new TempObj(
    x.CallByName(iNewPropertyName).ToString());
```

Now you can do `Intersect` or `Except` on `listNew` and `listOrig`, which will compare the property names. You can then pull the `Item` values from the resulting list.

Comment: yes, I think that is what I'm looking for. But how should I build the comparer ? For example, List<OldCar> originalList, List<NewCar> newList. And I want to intersect with the oldCar.brand and newCar.fullName properties ?

Answer (score 1):

Your class actually isn't generic here (although it should be), only your methods are.

Try this:

```
public class ListObjectComparator<T>
{

    #region Public Methods

    public static IEnumerable<T> Run(IEnumerable<T> originalItems, IEnumerable<T> newItems, Func<T,T,bool> comparer)
    {
        foreach(var originalItem in originalItems)
        {
            bool found = false;
            foreach (var newItem in newItems)
            {
                if (comparer(originalItem,newItem))
                {
                    found = true;
                    itemToRemove = newItem;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (found)
            {
                newItems.Remove(itemToRemove);
                yield return originalItem;
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Run compares originalItems with newItems and returns a list of items that are the same using the ComparePredicate you supply.

An example of use is:

```
List<int> firstList;
List<int> secondList;

List<int> common = ListObjectComparator<int>.Run(firstList,secondList, ((f,s) => return f< s));
```

The compare predicate here will return all ints in list1 where list 1 was less than the equivalent int in list 2.

EDIT: I should add that you shouldn't reinvent the wheel, you could always use an [IEqualityComparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class of your own.

Comment: You can convert the `delegate` into a `Func<T, T, bool>` parameter.

Comment: Your method crashes if one list has more items than the other.

Comment: Your method expects the order to be the same. That is, if one list is `{1, 2}` and the other is `{2, 1}`, it produces different output than the OP's method.

Comment: Good point, all three, will make modifications and edit.

Comment: Edited to not expect ordered list, to not require same list lengths and to use a Func<T,T,bool>, but I still recommend an IEqualityComparer.